# Performing a sum() on a collection in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, aggregate-functions, eloquent, relationship

I have an application with a basic forum system where users can "like" a topic multiple times. My models extend Eloquent and I'm trying to get the sum of votes a user has for a specific topic... Basically, I'm trying to accomplish something like:

```
$votes = Auth::user()
    ->votes->has('topic_id', '=', $topic->id)
    ->sum('votes');
```

However, when executing this, I get the following error...

> Call to a member function sum() on a non-object

I've also tried

```
public function show($forumSlug, $topicSlug)
{
    $topic = Topic::whereSlug($topicSlug)->first();

    $votes = Topic::whereHas('votes', function ($q) use ($topic)
    {
        $q->where('topic_id', '=', $topic->id)->sum('votes');
    });

    dd($votes);
}
```

However, with that I receive an error stating:

> Unknown column 'ideas.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select sum(`votes`)
>   as aggregate from `votes` where `votes`.`idea_id` = `ideas`.`id` and
>   `idea_id` = 1)`

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this (Not sure about your relationship but give it a try):

```
$topic = User::with(array('topics' => function ($query) use ($topic_id) {
    // $query = Topic, so it's: Topic::with('votes')
    $query->with('votes')->where('topics.id', $topic_id);
}))->find(Auth::user()->id)->topics->first();

// Count of total votes
dd($topic->votes->count());
```

**P/S:** If it doesn't work then please post your model's relationship methods.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working, though I'm not sure I like this approach. I'd love to hear if anyone knows of a better way of doing this...

Basically, I used my relationships to filter() the votes and then used sum() on the filtered collection.

```
public function show($forumSlug, $topicSlug)
{
    $userId = is_null(Auth::user()) ? false : Auth::user()->id;
    $topic = Topic::whereSlug($topicSlug)->first();

    $votes = $topic->votes->filter(function ($votes) use ($userId)
    {
        return $votes->user_id == $userId;
    })->sum('votes');

    return View::make('forums.topics.show', compact('topic', 'votes'));
}
```